# Solving errors with a stacktrace

Tags: java, android, stack-trace

I got an error that its stacktrace doesn't reveal where in my classes (& line number) the error lies.
Is there another way I can locate the code that causes this error?

I understand the error itself... but there are a couple of places in my code that could cause this and I can't reproduce it... (got the stacktrace from a user report).

Here's the stacktrace:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@462e1370 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:566)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Two things, is that the entire stack trace? If it is, you can use the log functions to hunt down which line in your code is causing the problem by adding log messages to your different functions.

Comment: This is the entire stack trace I got from the user report (in the developers admin).
Your suggestions is of course great but unfortunately I didn't use LOG in many places in my code... definitely will :)
Any other option?

Comment: @liorry: I'm thinking that the exception is coming from a different thread. This seems to be the event thread of Android while you execute code in the worker thread that results in code being executed in the event thread. Like slayton suggested add some comments. However, also try to comment out parts of the code and see what line causes that exception.

Comment: As I wrote, I can't reproduce this error... so commenting out parts of the code won't do but thanks for the tip regarding to the thread.. I think maybe I have an idea where it is :)

Comment: @liorry: if you want me to write my comment as an answer you can pick, let me know :)

Comment: Please do :) I found the location because of your answer.

Comment: @liorry: please prefix comments with the user you are commenting on like I do in this comment. That way that user will receive a notice. I had to recheck if this was updated and if you needed further assistance.

Comment: @sjngm sorry :) thanks for adding the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment is now an answer as requested:

I'm thinking that the exception is coming from a different thread. This seems to be the event thread of Android while you execute code in the worker thread that results in code being executed in the event thread. Like slayton suggested in his comment add some comments. However, also try to comment out parts of the code and see what line causes that exception.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably trying to show a dialog when the user has paused or killed the app. Check all your alertDialogs and how you show these. Make sure your activity is running. For example you could use [isFinishing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29)